# SignalR.Core not sending message on specific idp

Tags: signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, idp

I have signalR.Core on .Net6 for the server and angular on client.
I have on local/developpement environnement an idp based on IdentityServer 4.
On the quality environement the idp is sign&go.

With the identityServer idp, everything works well, I received all message on my angular application.
But with sign&go, I'm able to connect on server/client side but I'm not able to receive anything.

After check on logs, I saw that messages isn't sending by the server
(on local I have something like this on log
[image: websocket sample])

But with sign&go I have no errors, no specific logs and the hub send function is called without issue.
I have also no specific logs on client side.

Nothing specific on idp as well.

I tried these kind of transports Websocket/LongPooling/Server Sent Events but all types have the same result at the end (working with my idp but not with sign&go).

I tried on local with sign&go same result also.

Logs are already activated on server/client side.

Do you have a way to identify the source of non sending message ?

PS : The result is the same for all sending message.

Comment: The first suggestion for you, trying to uninstall  `sign&go` and check the phenomenon, if it work well, and this issue should related to `sign&go` .

Comment: The second suggestion, if it still not works after uninstalling the `sign&go` , pls disable your wondows firewall and disable the VPN if you have, then check again.

Comment: The third suggestion for this issue, due to the issue without any error logs, you can change the settings back and try to capture the network traffic in your issue server and local environment. Then compare the traffic, hope we can find more useful details.

Comment: I thanks for answers. I have no firewall, vpn was disabled, sign&go was  already unistall/reinstall. We already use wireshark to capture the traffic on local/server/sso environnement but nothing else. Yesterday I saw that the classic websocket call seems to work so I try to add all stuff that I need to have the previous feature with signalR